# how to use localStorage to set multiple <input>

Tags: reactjs

I want to achieve autosave user input, and when the page refresh, the user input not disappear.

There are two < input > for title and content.But when i run the code, I input 'a' to first < input >, the second  appear 'a' too. So how to separate two < input >

```
constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            title: localStorage.getItem('title') || '',
            content:  localStorage.getItem('content') || ''
        }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            title:e.target.value,
            content:e.target.value
        })
        localStorage.setItem('title', e.target.value)   
        localStorage.setItem('content', e.target.value)   
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <input type='text'
                        value={this.state.title}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                <input type='text'
                        value={this.state.content}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `name` properties to your code :

```js
handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
    //To update local storage
    localStorage.setItem(event.target.name, event.target.value);
}



render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <input
                type="text"
                name="title"
                value={this.state.title}
                onChange={e => this.handleChange}
            />
            <input
                type="text"
                name="content"
                value={this.state.content}
                onChange={e => this.handleChange)}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Very nice solution, taking all the necessary values from the event. +1

Comment: i want to use it in react-quill, but not work <Form onChange={this.handleChange}> <Form.Item { getFieldDecorator("content",{ initialValue:this.state.content, rules: [{ required: true}] })( <ReactQuill name='content' /> Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `handleChange` you are updating both state values with the input value. Updating each value separately should do the work:

```
handleChange(value, name) {
    this.setState({
        [name]: value
    });
    localStorage.setItem(name, value);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <input
                type="text"
                value={this.state.title}
                onChange={e => this.handleChange(e.target.value, "title")}
            />
            <input
                type="text"
                value={this.state.content}
                onChange={e => this.handleChange(e.target.value, "content")}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: You are welcome, @NadeemAhmad answer is more elegant; simply adding the name attribute solves the issue with less code.

Comment: i want to use it in react-quill, but not work <Form onChange={this.handleChange}> <Form.Item { getFieldDecorator("content",{ initialValue:this.state.content, rules: [{ required: true}] })( <ReactQuill name='content' /> Do you know why?

Comment: @zzm123 I haven't used react-quill. If `name` or similar property is not passed to the event the solution I'm proposing might work. See if it does, otherwise I think it's better to ask a new question with the code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

add `name` attribute to your `input` and access the name through `e.target.name`

I'm using [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to access `e.target.name` as `name` and `e.target.value` as `value` from the event parameter

```
handleChange({ target: { name, value }}) {
  this.setState({ [name]: value });
  localStorage.setItem(name, value); 
}

return (
  <div>
    <input type='text'
           name='title'
           value={this.state.title}
           onChange={this.handleChange}
    />
    <input type='text'
           name='content'
           value={this.state.content}
           onChange={this.handleChange}
    />
  </div>
);
```

Comment: i want to use it in react-quill, but not work

<Form 
          onChange={this.handleChange}>
<Form.Item 
          { getFieldDecorator("content",{
            initialValue:this.state.content,
            rules: [{ required: true}]
          })(
          <ReactQuill 
            name='content'   
          />
Do you know why?

Comment: @zzm123 react-quill provite a different onChange handler, you will need to take a look at the [docs](https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill)